# How to loop in react using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs, loops, npm

I got an error that `i` is not defined; I have initiated the `npm install jQuery` and I have import it

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

My code:

```
     isClick=()=>{
                   var allInput=$(".menu-list");
                   for(i=0; i<allInput.length; i++){
            allInput[i].on({
                click: function(){
                    alert("yes")
                }
            })

                   }
<button onClick={this.isClick}> click me</button>

          <nav className="menu pb-5">
                        <ul className="list-unstyled">
                           <li><NavLink className="menu-list " exact to="/">   <i className="fas fa-home"></i> <span> Home</span></NavLink></li>
                         <li><NavLink className="menu-list" to="/about-me"> <i className="far fa-user"></i> <span>About Me</span></NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink className="menu-list" to="/resume"> <i className="far fa-address-card"></i> <span>Resume</span></NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink className="menu-list" to="/portfolio"> <i className="far fa-address-card"></i> <span>Portfolio</span></NavLink></li>
                          <li><NavLink className="menu-list" to="/blog"> <i className="far fa-stop-circle"></i> <span>Blog</span></NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink className="menu-list" to="/contact"> <i className="fas fa-phone-volume"></i> <span>Contact</span></NavLink></li>                </ul>
                    </nav>
                }
```

Comment: Where is the isClick() function called?

Comment: kk sir check it now

Comment: 1) Why are you trying to use Jquery in React? It is usually recommended not to do that.
2) If you can provide details around what you want to do, maybe I can provide details around how to accomplish it using React only

Comment: You have to write `for(var i=0...)`. Note the `var` keyword.

Comment: how can we get in touch give me your skype name

Answer (score 0):

The error in the image is about `i` declaration; (notice the `let` keyword)

```
...
   for(let i=0; i<allInput.length; i++){
...
```